# Align elements in a table

Tags: html, css, html-table, drupal-7, alignment

I have a table with 3 columns, inside each `<td>` there are 3 `<div>` (title, image and description) in vertical position (one under the other).

I want to horizontally align all the images in the different cells, but depending on the title long (1 or 2 rows, even 3), the image will go down and won't be perfectly aligned with the rest of the images.

I have tried several combinations of `"vertical-align"`, `"display:flex;"`, even `"width"` or `"height"`, but I haven't found a solution.

Is there a way to achieve it?

This is the scheme:

```
<table>
    <tr> 
        <td>
            <div class="title"> ...   </div>    
            <div class="image">  ... </div>
            <div class="description">  ... </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I suppose you can not split these three divs in to three (table) rows?

Comment: You can restrict the title to few characters and show ellipsis(...) at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's ok for you, but you could achieve this with jQuery like so ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/sq0eyqqh/)):

HTML

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="title">title1<br/>test<br/>test test</div>
            <div class="img"><img src="" /></div>
            <div class="descr">description</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="title">title2<br/>test</div>
            <div class="img"><img src="" /></div>
            <div class="descr">description</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="title">title3</div>
            <div class="img"><img src="" /></div>
            <div class="descr">description</div>
        </td>
    </tr>        
</tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
width: 100%;
table-layout: fixed;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

jQuery

```
var heightAr = [];
var titleDiv = $('div.title');
titleDiv.each(function() {
    var height = $(this).css('height').replace('px', '');
    heightAr.push(height);
});
var greatest = Math.max.apply( null, heightAr );
titleDiv.css({'height':greatest + 'px'});
```

---

**Here is** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/sq0eyqqh/)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to divide a row into 3 cols, you should use td instead of all div like this: 
[image]

Comment: See, the problem is this is a Drupal view, therefore I can't change the code. I've got what I've got....